# First occurence of a word in a text with JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text where there are 6 occurrences of "Marine".

I want to find in this text the first occurrence of the word only and replace it by "Plane" for example.

I tried with this RegEx:

```
var myRegEx = new RegExp("^(.*)Marine(.*)$","gmi");
```

But it gives me the 4th, 5th, 6th occurrences...

Comment: are they separated by space? can they be anywhere?

Comment: Remove the `g` from your `RegExp` flag

Comment: @putvande: No, the first `.*` must be turned into a lazy dot matching pattern (following the current logic). Looks like OP comes from Java :)

Comment: if not try this :- https://regex101.com/r/pO1bM2/1

Comment: `var myRegEx = new RegExp("Marine","i");`, would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to find in this text the first occurrence of the word only and replace it by "Plane" for example.

```
var myRegEx = new RegExp("Marine","i");
```

*or*

`\\b` word boundary helps to do a exact match.

```
var myRegEx = new RegExp("\\bMarine\\b","i");
```

or

```
str.replace(/\bmarine\b/i)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without `regex` also

```
"Marine Marine Marine Marine Marine Marine".replace('Marine','Plane')
//"Plane Marine Marine Marine Marine Marine"
```

Comment: but this won't do case insensitive match.

Comment: Yep, but it wasn't in requirement ;)

Comment: I saw `i` in his regex.. And also this would replace `Marine` in `Marinea`